# Nodejs swagger integration - Express Router

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am aware of configuring swagger to my NodeJs project using **`JSON / YAML`**. Is there any way to automate the documentation like swagger doing for spring webservices.

**Note:** I am using Express Router to create endpoints.

Comment: Are you talking about server stub generators that create the boilerplate code for serverside? For example: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

Comment: Will it generate the swagger api-doc automatically by compiling all the routers in app like spring do for @RestController.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the package [swagger-autogen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-autogen) performs the automatic construction of the Swagger documentation.

First, install the package with: `npm i swagger-autogen`

If you have a endpoint/route file like this:

**routes.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const ToolsController = require('./controllers/ToolsController')

const router = express.Router()

const apiV1 = require('./controllers/ApiRoute1')

router.use('/v1', apiV1)

module.exports = router
```

Just declare a file called `swagger.js`, for example, with this:

**swagger.js**

```js
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')()

swaggerAutogen('./swagger-output.json', ['./routes.js']);
```

In the package.json, add a script such as:

```json
"scripts": {
    "swagger-autogen": "node ./swagger.js"
}
```

And run: `npm run swagger-autogen`

The Swagger documentation will be in the swagger-output.json.

To add descriptions, tags, summary, and so on, access the https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-autogen#endpoints

Examples: Links to projects that cover the simplest use of this module as well as the most complete use. See the links below:

[Example using Router](https://github.com/davibaltar/example-swagger-autogen-with-router)

[Example without Router](https://github.com/davibaltar/example-swagger-autogen)

Answer (score -1):

yes, you could use swagger-ui-express or other npm libraries =)

Comment: I think swagger-ui-express requires .json or .yaml for api-docs.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva Ok, sorry! You could try with TSOA. https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsoa

Comment: I am using express to create my endpoints. From the link, you shared I  can understand that is for typescript routers.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva mmm ok, I use typescript with node ... and swagger-jsdoc?

Answer (score -1):

You can use jsdoc. For this you need to install npm packages

```
npm i swagger-jsdoc
npm I swagger-ui-express
```

Please refer

[node js swagger with express server](https://medium.com/@sethigoldy/integrate-implementing-swagger-inline-api-documentation-with-node-js-express-server-e2a4e8920618)